# Google Apps Script admin SDK speed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

i'm creating a google sheet which translates given data from schools to a admin SDK Upload to Google Apps.
I know there a create user limit of 10 per second, hence the 120ms Delay time.
but, when coloring each row in sheets which is processed the speed is around 500ms - 2 seconds per entry.
Which causes the script to stop at the maximum execution time, because there are more than 600 users to be added.
Where does it go  wrong?

```js
function UploadUsers() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Upload");
ss.setActiveSheet(sh); 

var column = sh.getRange('A1:I5000');

  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call

  
  var uploadRows = 0;
  while ( values[uploadRows][0] != "" ) {
    uploadRows++;
  }

  var i=0
  var uiACU = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ACUsersMessage0= "Upload Users";
  var ACUsersMessage1= "Indien u op OK drukt worden er : "+ uploadRows + " Users aangemaakt! " 
                       
    var result = uiACU.alert( 
   ACUsersMessage0,
   ACUsersMessage1,
         uiACU.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
 
  if (result == uiACU.Button.OK) { 
 for (i=0; i<uploadRows;i++){

var uniqueId=[i][0];
var mailAdress=values[i][3];
var voorNaam=values[i][1];
var achterNaam=values[i][2];
var Ou=values[i][8];
var Pass=values[i][4];



   Utilities.sleep(12);
  
 AdminDirectory.Users.insert ({
   "kind": "admin#directory#user",
   "password" : Pass,
   "primaryEmail": mailAdress,
   "orgUnitPath": Ou,
   "changePasswordAtNextLogin": "TRUE",
   "name": {
      "givenName": voorNaam,
      "familyName": achterNaam,
   },
    "externalIds": [
      {
    "value": uniqueId,
    "type": "account",
    "customType": "gappsUniqueId"
      }
  ]
   })   
   
 ss.getRange("D"+ (i+1)).setBackground("red")  

}    
 
    
  } else {
     //Full Stop
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It goes wrong because every google script function has the 6minutes execution time, you can convey this in a couple of ways:

Read the [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices), the most important thing in there is to do thing in batches, instead of getting just a ROW and turn it RED, get several ROWs and do the sime, 1 ROW costs you 500ms, 20 ROWs will cost 505ms. There's probably a way for batch insert the users also, but I don't use the AdminSDK.

If there's no Batch for user insert, you can monitor the time of execution of the function in the beggining of the `for()`, if the time comes close the 6minutes (I recommend stopping at 5), save the last ROW inserted in the [properties service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/), create a [Progamatic Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) that will run the function again in 7minutes, then paint the ROWs red. It will take a long time to run entirely, but will work.

```
function insertUsers(){
   var timeStart = new Date().getTime();
   var rowStart = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastRow') || 0;

   for( from rowStart to endOfSheet ){
      if( (new Date().getTime()) - timeStart > (5 * 60 * 1000) ){
         PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastRow', currentRow);

      createTriggerToRun-insertUsers-in6Minutes;

      return 1;
     }

   // code to insert users here
   }
}
```

Comment: the paint red was just added for Illustration to see where the timeout happend and how fast the admindirectory.users was running.
when i call another function in this function will it have 6 minutes (5 to be save) again, or is it the total runtime of the 'master' script that's limited to 6 minutes (eg make a seperate function with 1-249 250-499 etc) and just call that script with a return a couple of times ?

Comment: Every function run has the 6 minutes limit, it resets after a time, but even GDEs don't know exactly how much time it is, so we'll just play safe and go with 6 minutes delay. I'll update the original answer on how to make a new funciton run again, it's actually the same, but it retrieves the row to start from the properties service.

Comment: @RichardvanderPlas There, sorry for the lazy code, don't have much time right now.